# extract list of user id's from views to tag a content automatic

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I want to extract a list of users id's from views to automatic tag the user generated content.

The function is important because a company should be able to make a list of users receiving their ads. These ads are a defined content type they are able to make and it would be great if these user id's could be tagged automatically. This is the only way (as I see it) I am able to control which users are exposed to these ads, because in most instances its only part of a group that should be exposed to it.

Can anyone help me with making this functionality, either in code or through modules I do not know about.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to list the advert nodes and assign the relevant field information though 'Modify entity values' action

It will allow you to filter and select the adverts to update then batch update them.

Comment: I dont quite understand this. Will this attach user tags to the ads?

Answer (score 0):

If the companies need to target who sees their ads, perhaps you could create a [Taxonomy](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy) of ad categories, then tag the ad nodes with them.

Add a taxonomy term field to the advertisement content type and to your users (you could call it `field_ad_category`), and use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to show only ads that match the viewer's ad categories.

Would need bit more info about how/where the ads need to show up to give more detail about the Views settings.

*Edit: The core [Statistics](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/statistics) module can keep track of page views out of the box, and integrates nicely with Views. Perhaps you can add a field to the advertisement content type that specifies how many hits the company has paid for, then additionally limit the View to ads with `field_max_hits` greater than their total views (a field made available in Views by the Statistics module).

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I am not able to only expose it to some in a group. If I have a user group of 200 with the same interest, but only want to expose it to 100 of them. I want to be able to control how many the company's ads are exposed to because the companies should pay for number og exposes.